# Is this SPI Flash?

Tags: identification, flash-memories

I'm currently reversing a device that has a chip soldered I can't identify. It's next to its controller, and judging from its size and position, it could be SPI Flash. It's SOP-8.

Does someone know the type? Do you have a data sheet?

[image: ente]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is indeed a 16M bit SPI flash chip made by [Gigadevice Semiconductor Inc.](http://www.gigadevice.com/index.html), a Beijing (China) based fabless semiconductor company.

[Data sheet](http://www.gigadevice.com/product/download/410.html?locale=en_US) is available from their website.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The manufacturer logo looks unfamiliar to me, but that part number is very similar to that of a 16Mbit SPI flash, yes. [Winbond Data Sheet](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Winbond%20PDFs/W25Q16BV.pdf)

[image]

If you look at the pinout:

1. I would bet that R93 is the CS# pull-up resistor,
2. R94 is a series termination resistor on DO from the chip.
3. R95 is probably tying off this pin to VCC to disable write protection
4. Connected to what appears to be the surface ground plane
5. Connected to external DI
6. Connected to external CLK
7. R5 is probably tying off this pin to VCC to disable write protection
8. C10xx are decoupling on the power pin.

[Here](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Winbond%20PDFs/W25Q16BV.pdf) is the datasheet I referenced -- no guarantee the opcodes are the same, but I'd give it >90% chance that this is a lower-cost SPI flash that's supposed to be pin-compatible with the 25Q "family", so to speak.